# $1 bet, 1000 events, 45% chance of winning each event. What are the odds of winning?

Tags: probability

Bet size: $1
Number of bets: 1000
Chance of winning each bet: 45%

What are the statistics around this problem?  Such things as:
What are the chances of being ahead after 1000 bets?  (ahead more than \$100 dollars?)
How big of a bankroll do you need for a 50% of getting to the 1000th bet before going broke?
With $100$ what is the average number of bets before going broke?  (with \$200?)
What formulas are used so I could look at different options?

Answer (score 0):

You have a [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)  Using the Wikipedia notation, your first is $n=1000, p=0.45$ and you sum over $k$ from $501$ to $1000$.  Ahead more than $100$ is sum over $k$ from $551$ to $1000$  I'll leave the rest to you.  With $1000$ throws at $45\%$ you are not going to win.